# Creating new bot from template using API in botpress

Tags: botpress

Is it possible to create a BotPress bot entirely using the API? More specifically, can I accomplish most of all of what I would do in the UI by just using API methods? I looked, and I don't see a `createBot()` method, so I'm wondering if this is possible.

Second question, I read that multi-tenant support has been added in version 11. Is there any documentation on how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, if you use the F12 on your browser to see how Botpress works under the hood. you will find that it uses some API.

Here are some I found and used :

- **Bots management**:  /api/v1/admin/bots
- **QNA management**:  /api/v1/bots/{botid}/mod/qna/questions
- **Managing a specifi bot**:  /api/v1/admin/bots/{botid}
- ...

Keep looking and you will find more than that.